# plugabble wp_authenticate function not works from wp-login.php

Tags: plugin-development, pluggable

I created in my plugin a `wp_authenticate` function:

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_authenticate' ) ) :
     function wp_authenticate( $username, $password )
     {
```

inside this function, if it's the first login I change the password stored in the database (I do this because the password was saved after a data porting from a Magento site, so it needs to be updated with `wp_hash_password()`).

If you are logged in from the page

`/wp-login.php`

the password is updated, but the login is not performed. The login works from the next attempt.

If instead the login is performed from the page

`/my_account`

everything works fine from the first attempt.

Because?

Comment: `wp_authenticate` is already a function in WordPress, I'm guessing you're trying to use a pluggable function? Pluggable functions are a very very old WordPress feature that predate the hooks/actions/filters system which people use today. This is not how it is done today. You would be much better off with the https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate/ hook which is more compatible and easier to use than what you've done. The doc I linked to also has user contributed examples of custom authentication

Comment: Yes, you are right, pluggabe function is old.
I tried with a hook initially, but the problem was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the login procedure pre-loads the USER object in cache.

The password that is checked is always the initial one: changing the password in the database only works from the next login attempt.
I fixed it by adding

```
clean_user_cache($userId)
```

But I don't understand why if I try to login from the "my account" page, the user cache is not considered.

Maybe it's because of the absence of the "remember me?" flag.